# Exception in reduce task of a Pig Script in runPipeline function

Tags: apache-pig

I'm getting below exception in the reduce task of a Pig Script. I have googled it around, but I'm unable to find a reason for this. Could anyone please throw some light on it ?

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:465)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:428)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:408)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:572)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
```

Comment: Are you running this as a Pig script, or embedded in Java (PigServer)?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus I'm running this as a pig script.